# A view with two controls, bound to the same data

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I'm wondering how I can go about having 1 view with two `ItemsControl`, bound to the same view model.

This is what I have:

ViewModels:

- **MonitoredItemViewModel.cs**
- **MonitoredItemsViewModel.cs** (Contains property BindableCollection MonitoredItems, and some commands)

Views:

- **MonitoredItemView.xaml**
- **MonitoredItemsView.xaml** (Display a collection of MonitoredItemViewModel, using two different controls)

In my MonitoredItemsView.xaml I want to have a WpfToolkit `DataGrid` to display details about every object in the `MonitoredItems`-collection, and an `ItemsControl` where I want to display the same data, but in a different way (as according to MonitoredItemView.xaml)

By setting

```
<wtk:DataGrid x:Name="MonitoredItems" Height="Auto" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" Width="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
...
</wtk:DataGrid>
```

Caliburn.Micro solves this for the datagrid, based on the name.

How do I go about getting my ItemsControl to bind to the same data?
The binding works by setting

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MonitoredItems, Mode=TwoWay}">
...
</ItemsControl>
```

but then I don't get the Caliburn.Micro-magic that templates each item according to the **MonitoredItemView.xaml**

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm having some trouble following your question.  You list two viewmodels, but you want the view bound to the same data?  Do you mean the same data in a single view model?  Why do you have two viewmodels in your example?

Comment: I will try to clarify my original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the `Bind.Model` attached property

e.g.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MonitoredItems, Mode=TwoWay}" cal:Bind.Model="{Binding PathToVMToBindTo}">
    ....
</ItemsControl>
```

CM will then apply it's conventions using the `ViewModelBinder`

If in doubt read the CM docs on the CodePlex site (they are pretty concise compared to a lot of other projects) and check the source on there too:

http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=All%20About%20Conventions&referringTitle=Documentation

and here's what the `Model` attached property on the Caliburn Micro `Bind` class does:

```
/// <summary>
///   Hosts dependency properties for binding.
/// </summary>
public static class Bind
{
    /// <summary>
    ///   Allows binding on an existing view. Use this on root UserControls, Pages and Windows; not in a DataTemplate.
    /// </summary>
    public static DependencyProperty ModelProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "Model",
            typeof(object),
            typeof(Bind),
            new PropertyMetadata(null, ModelChanged)
            );

    static void ModelChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Execute.InDesignMode || e.NewValue == null || e.NewValue == e.OldValue)
        {
            return;
        }

        var fe = d as FrameworkElement;
        if (fe == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        View.ExecuteOnLoad(fe, delegate
        {
            var target = e.NewValue;
            var containerKey = e.NewValue as string;

            if (containerKey != null)
            {
                target = IoC.GetInstance(null, containerKey);
            }

            d.SetValue(View.IsScopeRootProperty, true);

            var context = string.IsNullOrEmpty(fe.Name)
                              ? fe.GetHashCode().ToString()
                              : fe.Name;

            ViewModelBinder.Bind(target, d, context);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, will try to answer here, but I confess I have not used Caliburn.Micro before.

If you have two `ItemsControls` on the view and you want them bound to the same collection in a single view model object, then the standard binding mechanics will work.  There is no (real) limitation to how many controls can be bound to the same property.

If you want each control to display the data differently, the accepted approach is to override the `ItemTemplate` of the `ItemsControl` with a `DataTemplate` that lays out the data however you want it.  Those `DataTemplate`s can be placed in a separate resource dictionary for re-use.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I will do it the standard WPF-way for now.

Comment: Works but you can get all the CM magic using CM's `Bind.Model` attached property